# Game seems to freeze after hitting just outside of any button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I'm a little new to Swift & Xcode, though slowly making my way through understanding it..

Game visually seems to freeze and shows the partial curl/"page flip" segue animation, and there are no crash logs or anything given. I was just able to (somehow) get an error, once:

> Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before
> next touch

and googling this I found something about turning off multitasking gestures, but I can't seem to figure out where that is, and I'm not 100% sure that's the issue (though it is likely)

Anyone know where to find "multitasking gestures" (I remember something about settings panel, but I don't really know where that is either..) or have an idea of what the issue is and how to fix it?

Edit: I don't know of any point in my code that I use any gesture recognizers or anything. I usually just set a func UIButton and connect it to the Storyboard for Touch Down. I would send my code but I have several view controllers and several cocoa touch files, and it seems to happen on all of them - 3 for sure that I've tested. Tapping a lot on the screen also causes the crash sometimes.
I am using the latest versions (that I know of) of Swift and Xcode.

Update: I changed the partial curl segue animations to cross dissolve (basically anything other than partial curl) and it seems to fix the issue. I'm not sure why exactly the partial curl causes it or a workaround/fix though. I do have them using Full Screen but I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: Set the right tags.  If you just say 'Game,' nobody but you knows whether you are using UIKit, Sprite Kit, Scene Kit or whatever to design a game.

Comment: Oops, thank you. Wasn't sure all the tags I needed, and I forget there's SpriteKit and SceneKit. I fixed it, let me know if I forgot anything else